# How do I center a grid column title in xaml?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to center the column titles of a grid in xaml (using Xamarin framework).
I have the following line of code:

```
<dg:DataGridColumn Title="Name" PropertyName="TName" Width="1.2*" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" CellTextMargin="10,0,0,0"/>
```

This centers the column text, but not the title. How can I fix this?

Edit: this is specifically for the grid control from the NuGet package Plugin.Controls.DataGrid v. 0.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to set `HorizontalHeaderAlignment="Center"`.

Answer (score 0):

`HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"` as you have it should do the work but `Center` is already the default alignment Option for the Column Titles meaning that if you do not specify anything it will be centered (by default).

You can see this in the source code [here](https://github.com/akgulebubekir/Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid/blob/4036b2d82f4006c85f2cca469147370822e8f1ff/Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid/DataGridColumn.cs#L29). One of the beauty of OSS.

Remove the whole `HorizontalContentAlignment` from the Column.

Hope this helps.-

Comment: Thanks for your response! When I remove the `HorizontalContentAlignment` portion, I notice that the data within the grid is centered but the Title remains left-aligned. I also removed the `CellTextMargin` and `Width` settings, but did not get any improvement.